# How to blacklist Microsoft Keys in secureboot

Tags: secure-boot

I recently  managed to get secure boot working on my system with Arch Linux. I am using custom keys over preloader/shim I would like to blacklist Microsoft's key. Is this possible. If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be surely done via UEFI BIOS. Boot into it and select:

"Delete All Secure Boot Keys" - this option name is BIOS dependent.

Then proceed to install your own MAK key again:

- https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html
- https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html

Comment: I would like to add the Microsoft key to the DBx to black list it. Is that possible?

Comment: If you remove it, there's no need to blacklist it.

Comment: Some UEFI systems will only provide the option to delete the primary key (PK) - this will enable Secure Boot Setup Mode, which allows replacing all the keys freely until a new PK is installed. If the UEFI BIOS has no other options, you will need another tool for modifying the keys - the `keytool` in [efitools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jejb/efitools.git) includes a stand-alone `keytool.efi`. Put it on USB stick as `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` then boot from the stick, and you can edit Secure Boot keys on any Secure Boot system, if you first can get the system to Setup Mode.